# python-requests 2.7.0 extremely slow with Python2.7 in SSL

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, python-requests, sni

I'm using python-requests with a REST API to upload files using post method. But I am facing extremely slow transfers when using SSL.

```
import requests
session = requests.session()
session.post("https://my_url", files={'filedata': open('my_file', 'rb')})
```

I'm in a situation where I only face this problem with Python2.7 with requests==2.7.0.
Here are my results:

Python2.7 with requests==2.7.0 with SSL -> 100ko/s

Python2.7 with requests==2.4.3 with SSL -> 21mo/s

Python3.4 with requests==2.7.0 with SSL -> 21mo/s

Python3.4 with requests==2.4.3 with SSL -> 21mo/s

Note that with HTTP (without SSL) I do not have any problem.

I've profiled my call with Pycharm (https://linx.li/selif/uj1q1akc8.svg) where we can see that all process time occurs in WrappedSocket.sendall(), a function in urllib3 contrib file PyOpenSSL : https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/blob/1.10/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py#L223

I've also tested the upload with multiple files:

- 5mo/10mo/20mo are uploading normally
- 100mo+ are uploading slowly

Do you have any idea what could be the problem and solution?

Comment: This is probably due to the ciphers used. Older versions of requests allow the cheap and insecure RC4 will newer don't. If the server then only offers slow ciphers like DES-CBC3 then everything will be much slower.

Comment: it not also depends on the ciphers on the server but also on the client and on the order. If you make a packet capture one can see which cipher gets used.